# Goでstring型スライスにアクセス出来ない

Tags: go

```
[ あああ ]
type: []string
```

上記のようなスライス`tweet`に`tweet[0]`のようにアクセスしようとしましたが、からの文字を参照してしまいます。なぜでしょうか。

コードは下記のようになっています。

```
tweet := g.getTweets(1)
fmt.Printf("%v", tweet) // [ あああ ]と表示される
fmt.Printf("%T", tweet) // []stringと表示される
fmt.Printf("%v", tweet[0]) //何も表示されない。あああと表示されてほしい

//スライス生成部
func (g *Game) getTweets(num int) []string {
    results := make([]string, num)
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        results = append(results, <-g.tweetCh)
    }
    return results
}
```

channelの送信部分

```
// StartPublicFilterStream start stream api
func (s *Stream) StartPublicFilterStream(v url.Values, wg *sync.WaitGroup, tweetCh chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    stream := s.client.PublicStreamFilter(v)

    for {
        item := <-stream.C
        switch status := item.(type) {
        case anaconda.Tweet:
            s.CurrentTweet = status.Text
            tweetCh <- status.Text
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

clientというのは https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda のものです。

Comment: もしかして、tweet の内容が `[]string{"", "あああ", ""}` となっていませんか(`tweet[0]` は空文字列)？

Comment: そうです。何も表示されないので空文字列だと思います

Comment: 今少し調べましたがインデックス0が空文字でインデックス1に文章が入っていました。なぜかわかりますか。1しか割り当ててないのになぜ2つ要素があるのでしょうか

Comment: `<-g.tweetCh` の部分ですが、この channel に出力している部分はどうなっているのでしょう？

Comment: Channel送信部を本文に追加しました。

Comment: ああ、分かりました。`results := make([]string, num)` を `results := make([]string, 0, num)` にしてみて下さい。

Comment: できました! ありがとうございます! なぜこのようなことになるのでしょうか。他のところでもmakeを使っているので良ければご教授頂けますか。

Comment: append の場合、`slice[len(slice)]` に値を追加します。num が 1 なので、results[1] に値がセットされてしまった、というわけです。ただ、今回の場合は確保するスライスの長さが予め分かっていますので、`make` はそのままにして、`results[i] = <-g.tweetCh` とした方が分かりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど。わかりました。ありがとう御座います。確かに長さは確保できているのでそのようにするべきでした。